# How MOV BYTE PTR instruction works?

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

I want to know how exactly MOV BYTE PTR instruction works, I have one example here that I can't understand the result. Check it:

```
MOV CL,BYTE PTR DS:[ESI]

----Ollydbg show this------
DS:[01EA22E0]=41 ('A')
CL=B0
```

Why CL = B0? Why CL isn't 41? If I go to ESI in dump, I have this

```
01EA22E0: 41 47 00 C5 B9 F1 63 3C... But any B0 ;(
```

Check my print:

[image: mov byte ptr]

I really need to solve this, any help will be welcome.

Comment: Probably because you are using DS register to specify the segment. Try to remove it and just do `MOV CL,BYTE PTR [ESI]`

Comment: @Elalfer: I think if you don't specify DS:, you get it by default, so I don't think that will help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ollydbg.  Did you actually *step* past the instruction, so it got executed?  What you show is consistent with the instruction *about* to be executed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because the debugger is stopped at that instruction, it wasn't actually executed yet.  You'll have to single-step one more time to see the CL register updated with the content of memory.